# Joomla jQuery('hasTooltip').tooltip() error

Tags: jquery, twitter-bootstrap, joomla

[Link](http://ketanmehta.demojoomla.com)

Getting `jQuery('.hasTooltip').tooltip()` is not defined error. I have searched before posting and tried following things before posting here

1. Embedded latest bootstrap.min.js
2. Inserted `JHtml::_('jquery.framework');` at the top
3. Tried to remove hasTooltip on document load.

but still I'm failed to do so.

[Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sJnSO.png)

Also another 2 error is showing in chrome console... Not getting exact issue even after searching a lot. any suggestion/help would be appreciated.

Comment: "hasTooltip" isn't an element... maybe a class, and if yes, you should use a dot, like this: ".hasTooltip"

Comment: @WashingtonGuedes Yes, you're right, it was typo. but issue is same. can you check the link and see the console ?

Comment: @KetanMehta once you are able to remove extra bracket, it may stop getting error.

Answer (score 0):

you have extra bracket after --> });

```
jQuery('#maximenuck148').DropdownMaxiMenu({
    fxtransition : 'jswing',dureeIn : 0,dureeOut : 500,menuID : 'maximenuck148',testoverflow : '0',orientation : 'vertical',behavior : 'mouseover',opentype : 'slide',fxdirection : 'normal',directionoffset1 : '30',directionoffset2 : '30',showactivesubitems : '0',ismobile : 0,menuposition : '0',effecttype : 'dropdown',fxduration : 500
    });
```

please remove it and put this code in document ready event

Comment: I'm using Joomla CMS, It is generated using plug-in CK Maximenu automatically, So what is the possibility of syntax error in code ?

Comment: don't know, maybe some one other can suggest. before using anything it's better you learn it better.

Comment: try to ask your joomla question here, that how it's coming http://joomla.stackexchange.com/ as i think you now know what js issue is atleaset get solved as per suggestion.

Answer (score 0):

You don't have any element with this class. Look:

[image]

As consequence, $(".hasTooltip") returns *undefined* and you can't assign any function to *undefined*.

---

I believe a plugin only causes error when we already went wrong before.
So.. let's see the first message error:

[image]

Remove this extra "<script>" and wait to see the new results.

Comment: So how do I remove this code on document load event ? because, This code is generated by plug-in and I do not have control over its output.

Comment: I'm not able to see extra <script> tag. I used Ctrl + U to view source code.

Comment: @KetanMehta Probably, at some point of your code, you are adding this <script>